# I need a pronunciation tip

Tags: pronunciation

I need to know from a native speaker whether the **TH** in the word "foul-mouthed" can be pronounced as **F**. I find it very difficult to make a **D** sound after the **TH**.

Comment: Not by any normal pronunciation. There might be some dialects that pronounce it that way informally, but it would sound out of place if other words that were spoken didn't also adhere to that same dialect.

Answer (score 3):

That would be a normal pronunciation in some southern English (British) dialects, but not otherwise. Pronouncing one word as if you're from Essex would certainly come across as odd.

However, if your accent isn't near-perfect, people will not bat an eyelid at the odd slightly difference in pronunciation, so I wouldn't worry about it too much. "Mowfed" isn't a word itself, so you're not saying something people will get confused about.